# refrigerator running all the time

Tags: refrigerator

I bought a used refrigerator with 6 month parts and labor guarantee. It has cut off just twice in 4 days. It is at the right temperature, but won't cut off. I have called them, but repairman claims that it is because it is hot outside. What should I do?

Comment: Related question and one of [my preferred answers](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/my-fridge-runs-way-too-much-is-this-because-it-doesnt-seem-to-be-level/51717#51717) there (the other one being about leaky sealed units).

Comment: What is the room temperature where the refrigerator is installed? If it's very warm there, the repairman may be right. I chose a refrigerator at random, and the [manual](http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-LFX31925ST) says _The compressor will run longer under warm
conditions. At normal room temperatures (70°F)
expect your compressor to run about 40% to
80% of the time. Under warmer conditions,
expect it to run even more often. The refrigerator
should not be operated above 110°F._

Comment: Does the temperature in the refrigerator continue to drop, or is it holding steady?

Comment: @Johnny That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Tester101 I don't think the asker gave enough information to make my comment an answer. If he says it's in an air conditioned space at room temperature then high room temperature is not the problem

Comment: I would check the condition of the door seals and make sure the door is closing fully.